# Changing iOS textfield on the fly to show currency

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` that needs to show some currency data. The idea is that it should always show the formatted number with the $ symbol.

This is the code that I am using currently :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString*)string {



    [self performSelector:@selector(timeToSearchForStuff:) withObject:textField afterDelay:0.3];


    return YES;
}

- (void)timeToSearchForStuff:(UITextField*)textField
{
    if (textField.text.length == 0) {
        textField.text = @"$";
    }

    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
        [numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
        [numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];

    NSLocale *priceLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_AU"]  ;

    [numberFormatter setLocale:priceLocale];

    long long inuy =[[numberFormatter numberFromString:textField.text]integerValue];

    NSLog(@"starteo");

    NSLog(@"inuy :: %lld", inuy);

    NSString *formattedString =[numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithLong:inuy]];

    NSLog(@"chupacabra3 :: %@", formattedString);

    self.textField.text = formattedString;

}
```

This works fine until I type more than 4 digits, if I type the 5th digit, the textfield goes to zero.

If I just log the value, it performs ok, but if i set the text on 5th digit, it again goes to zero.

Need some help on what is going wrong here. Guide me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this condintion

```
if (textField.text.length == 0) {
    textField.text = @"$";
}
```

with this

```
if (textField.text.length == 0) {
    textField.text = @"$";
} else {
    [textField setText:[textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""]];
}
```